# Canvg - SVG Overflowing when using scale

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvg

Check this example here : https://jsfiddle.net/znbptw0c/

That SVG is extracted from amCharts library.

But when I change it to a canvas image using canvg and `transform : scale` on the SVG, it cuts off the scaled portion, how can I fix this?

I'm using scale because I need to increase resolution, not just size.

Changing the SVG width/height directly wouldn't be ideal as that could ruin some alignings in the bigger context, and I want the font size to increase also.

JS :

```
function svgToCanvas(svg){
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')
  canvg(canvas, svg.outerHTML);
  window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1.0))
  return canvas;
}
const svg = document.body.querySelector('svg');
svgToCanvas(svg)
```

HTML (too big, please check fiddle):

```
<svg version="1.1" style="position: absolute; width: 1366px; height: 693px; top: 0px; left: 0px;transform: scale(1.5);" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
</svg>
```

Comment: Do not scale. Use this: `<svg viewBox="0 0 1366 693" version="1.1" style="position: absolute;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` instead of what you have now

Comment: @enxaneta But I need to scale it to increase resolution, Also your solution just made a very tiny output

Comment: An svg element takes the size of the container. Maybe the problem is the container element. Also, you may try to play with the font size

Comment: If you don't mind the white space around the chart you may try a different viewBox: `<svg viewBox="330 0 700 693"  version="1.1" style="position: absolute;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`